# Moved a VM and unable to get network enabled *-network DISABLED

Tags: networking, vmware

I recently moved a VM from one host to another, I used vmware converter tool, the VM powers up fine but the network is broke on the vm. I tried to run sudo lshw -C network and I got *-network DISABLED.

Bit stumped here as the VM worked perfectly before the migration. 
What other info can i provide?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry disregard, I figured it out. I had to edit the vim /etc/network/interfaces

Had to change the adapter from the old ens160 to ens35 and reboot the machine. back online!